# Text alignment in <aside> and <main>

Tags: html, css, bulma

I've got 2 main sections on my website, aside and main both inside Bulma columns class.
And my problem here is headings are not aligned and I can't figure it out how to align them

IMG showing the problem
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLJmH.png

HTML:

```
<div class="columns">
<aside class="menu is-narrow sidebar">
<h3 class="title boxed-section-title is-4">Technologies</h3>
</aside>
<main class="column" role="main">
<h3 class="title boxed-section-title is-4">Job offers</h3>
<main>
```

CSS:

```
.boxed-section-title.title {
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
}
```

Comment: Care to post a codepen sample? based on what I see, I don't think it should be a problem.  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ROdPjK

Comment: Just copied everything related there, but it does not support Bulma hence it's displaying everything in one column
@Edit
Supporting Bulma
https://codepen.io/frohus/pen/YMgXap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that your headings are not vertically aligned, that's because of padding applied to main element because of `column` class which you've not to `aside`.

All you've to do is to apply `column` class to aside as well.

Here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dLrojp